# c - Method to Continue/Exit Program After User Input

Tags: c, loops, user-input, exit, do-while

For starters, I am new to C and programming in general. I have more experience with PowerShell and bash scripting, so apologies in advance for errors with headers, indentation, syntax, etc. Anyway, I'm trying to complete this program for a class, but I've had some trouble with one particular section, so I'm looking for some guidance as I'm pretty lost right now.

To provide some background: I'm supposed to allow a user to enter a user code between 6 and 10. This code uniquely identifies the user, who would then be asked for input for several other integer values, which would be totaled and averaged at the end. However, the user must be able to start the program again and enter another number (between 6 and 10); the user must then go through the previous process again to finish the program.

My problem is I **cannot** use if statements, break, continue, exit, abort or goto; I **must** use a do while loop to figure out when the user is done entering input; and I **must** provide error messages for when the user enters the wrong input, prompting them to enter it again.

With what I've posted below, I cannot figure out how to give the user an option to continue and/or exit without using if, break, continue, etc and while also prompting for error messages. I'm probably overthinking something but if anyone can provide some insight I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

     main()
    {

        int usercode; /* setting variables for user code */   

        do

        {
            printf ("Please enter your user code: ");
            scanf("%1d", secid);   /* user must input 1 digit code */

        } while(secid >= 6 || secid <= 10); /* code must be between numbers 6 and 10 */



    }
```

Comment: You are missing an & before secid like: scanf("%1d", &secid);

Comment: You don't show `secid` definition. I guess you copied this from a printed book and misread `%ld` as `%1d`, with `long int secid;` previously defined. Or, long live 20th century typewriters lacking a `1` key!

Comment: Oops my edit about typewriters has reverse-logic.

Comment: @WeatherVane My intention with %1d was to only take a single digit of input. Does it not do this?

Comment: It restricts the input when you enter more than one digit, but if you enter *only* one digit is not satisfied and `scanf` does not return until another entry is made. The danger too, is if you limit input into `scanf` the extra characters remain in the input buffer. But since you go on to restrict the input with `while(secid >= 6 || secid <= 10);` I don't see the point of it.

Comment: `main` signature should be at least `int main(void){}`

Comment: @Michi Do you mean just in terms of proper syntax or will/could this affect my code?

Comment: You should read about Hosted and Free-Standing environments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the loop for logging in, you use it for the other input

pseudocode:

```
get user id

do {    
  get a value    
} while (value is not pause or quit)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `while` at the end of a `do` `while` is like a repeated `if`. `If` will be asked again and again until it is false. Note that the block of `do` `while` will be executed at least once, because the cycle test is executed after the content of the block. You need `int secid` instead of `int usercode`. Inside the `do` `while` you need another `do` `while` to read the data and to calculate `sum` and `avg` in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int secid = -1;
    do {   
        printf("Please enter your user code: ");
        scanf("%1d", &secid);
    } while((secid < 6 || secid > 10) && printf("Error\n"));
    printf("The user code was %d", secid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this portion do? int argc, char **argv

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem, it is just that the compiler does not throw any warnings, if you want to know more details read this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: @DZDomi If you do not need `int argc, char **argv` Why is there? .. Why not `(void)` ?

Comment: cause it does not hurt to know about it :)

Comment: @DZDomi ...and by the way, SO is not a Tutorial Site.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but what the above does is set secid to -1, then run the loop while the value is less than 6 or more than 10. Then once in the loop, the user sets the value of secid to a digit between 6 and 10 or they get an error. This makes sense since the loop will just keep running while true.

Comment: it just executes the loop before checking any secid, theoretically you can set the value before the loop to anything besides 6-10. If this answer helped you please mark it as correct